# How to change frequency of messages in Veins-LTE

Tags: veins

I want to change the frequency of messages for `DSRC` and `LTE` on `Veins-LTE` framework.

Usually in regular `Veins` is done by changing the beacon interval in `omnetpp.ini` , but this does not show any changes in `Veins-LTE` framework.

The reason for this is that i want to have control on how many messages/second i am sending through `DSRC` and `LTE` and analyse the behaviours for different amount of messages/second.

The framework i am using is: http://veins-lte.car2x.org

Comment: Show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

You might be using the [SimpleApp](https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/veins-lte-1.3/veins/src/veins/modules/heterogeneous/application/SimpleApp.cc#L82) sample application in your simulation. In Veins LTE 1.3 this module is simply generating one message per second. See [line 82](https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/veins-lte-1.3/veins/src/veins/modules/heterogeneous/application/SimpleApp.cc#L82) for where this is done. If you want to change the interval, you will need to change this line (or change the code to have it read an OMNeT++ .ini parameter)

Comment: Great to hear from your!
I was checking that after i saw how is done in the BaseWaveApplLayer.
Would that generate same amount of messages for both DSRC and LTE or i should remove the IF Condition [line 71][1]  if i want to have the same amount of messages for both technologies.
[1]: https://github.com/floxyz/veins-lte/blob/veins-lte-1.3/veins/src/veins/modules/heterogeneous/application/SimpleApp.cc#L71